# Why does Rambam give such extensive treatment to the theories of the Mutakallemin

Tags: rambam, theology, moreh-nevuchim

In Chapter LXII of Moreh Nevuchim, Rambam presents a convincing argument as to the fallacy inherent in the machinations of the [Mutakallemin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam) theology, in particular, the proof of the existence of God.

But then in LXXIII - LXXV he presents extensive details of their theories and proofs thereof, only to further discredit them.

In the interest of full disclosure, I have only barely skimmed them, taking the mathematical stance that if the logical premises are incorrect, the application to any theorem/proof is (euphemistically) unproductive.

However, I would like to think I have given pretty extensive consideration to what has been written in earlier chapters, motivated by sound advice that there are many hidden gems within.

Maybe that's the case here. Or perhaps alternatively, the extensive coverage may be a nod to some validity therein.

Thanks

Comment: Rambam lived amongst Islam culture and dealt a lot with conversion to Islam. Isn't it natural?

Comment: @AlBerko: A variant... R Yosef ben Yehudah of Ceuta lived within a Muslim culture, and therefore was more likely to have been interested in his teacher's, the Rambam's, positions on topics the Kalam around him were promoting. He was the representative Perplexed person the Guide addresses; it is his questions to the Rambam that the book is built around.

Comment: @AlBerko Geographic and temporal proximity are not the exclusive driving factor. The _Guide_  deals to a large extent with Aristotelian philosophy, quite remote in time and distance. Actually my question was in the context of logic and academics. Having thrown out their methodology, why elaborate on an ill-conceived theory. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the answer lies in the HaRmBM's introductory remarks expressed in the letter to his student, R. Joseph ibn Aknin to whom the *Guide* seems to some extent be addressed. Ashe said: every word (i.e., no doubt including the Introduction) need to be carefully read:

"When I commenced by way of
hints, I noticed that you desired additional explanation, urging me to expound some metaphysical
problems; to teach you the system of the Mutakallemim; to tell you whether their
arguments were based on logical proof; and if not, **what their method was**. I perceived that
you had acquired some knowledge in those matters from others, and that you were perplexed
and bewildered; yet you sought to find out a solution to your difficulty."